# Найти кротчайший путь между объектами в массиве их ссылок

Tags: python, графы, структуры-данных

У меня есть массив объектов которые хранят ссылки друг на друга. Мне нужно найти кратчайший путь от одного объекта X до объекта Y если такой есть (если нету то об этом нужно заявить).

Я так понимаю что Дейкстра тут не потянет. Массив огромный **(Примерно 20,000,000 объектов)**. Чем его обойти и какой алгоритм поиска пути вы предложите и почему?
Возможно использование НЕ ТОЛЬКО нативных решений по этому пожалуйста прошу вас предлагать не только пути решения а так же и существующие библиотеки которые могут пригодиться.

Comment: Когда открывал вопрос, хотел посоветовать Дейкстру, но он почему-то не потянет... Тогда вот http://www.mit.edu/people/dimitrib/SLF.pdf  Хотя, самое простое, это A* использовать. Он явно быстрее Дейкстры будет.

Comment: @Suvitruf просто Дейкстра работает n^2 по времени. Но на самом деле я не специалист, просто предположил. Вы считаете что обычный Дейкстра сможет справиться?

Comment: Я не знаю, для какой это задачи вам надо. Я Дейкстру использую, к примеру, у AI в своей игре для поиска пути по графу с 200+ точками. Сколько у вас узлов?

Comment: @Suvitruf Примерно до  20,000,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментариям, у вас очень много узлов в графе. Не важно, какое решение вы выберите, если делать в лоб, то всё будет медленно. Если говорить про алгоритм Дейкстры.

Для начала вам необходимо разбить граф на части.

1. Разбить всё поле (граф) на подграфы.
2. Между этими графами обозначить соединительные узлы.
3. Теперь поиск пути начинается с графа ближайшего.

   - Если путь найден в рамках этого графа, то заканчиваем.
   - Если нет, то смотрим соединительные узлы.
   - Прогоняем ближайший граф от соединительной точки. Суммируем с результатам из прогонки предыдущего графа.
   - Продолжаем, пока не найдём путь.

Понятное дело, в угоду оптимизации мы теряем в оптимальности, вероятно, в некоторых аспектах.

Если же будете брать другой алгоритм, к примеру A*, то всё равно нужно как-то предподготовить данные, разбить на части, иначе у вас всё будет очень медленно и есть много памяти

Comment: Разбить всё поле (граф) на подграфы. - Для каждого объекта составить его собственный граф? Матрицы инцидентности/смежности?